# Вопрос про БИОС

Tags: bios

Если в БИОСе загрузить стандартные настройки (load setup defaults) данные с ПК исчезнут или нет???

Answer (score 1):

Данные хранятся не в BIOS. Назначение BIOS это базовая подсистема ввода\вывода. За хранение данных отвечает внешнее устройство, например жесткий диск.